# ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true) doesn't hide mapping routes from document

Tags: asp.net-core, openapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I expect this couple routes to be hidden because of `ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)`

```
app.MapPost("/login", [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)] async (string returnUrl, HttpContext context, [FromServices] SignInManager<LiteDbUser> signInManager) =>
{
    var form = context.Request.Form;
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(form["username"], form["password"], false, false);
    return result.Succeeded ? Results.Redirect(returnUrl ?? "/health") : Results.Redirect("/login");
});

app.MapGet("/logout", [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi=true)] async ([FromServices] SignInManager<LiteDbUser> signInManager) =>
{
    await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return Results.Redirect("/login");
});
```

but it seems there is no effect

[image]

Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: Is it just hidden for swashbuckle?

Comment: @QiangFu what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there's not way to use attributes in minimal API. But you could try add`.ExcludeFromDescription()` to hide an API.

```
app.MapGet("/test", string () => { return "test success"; }

).ExcludeFromDescription();
```

Then it will be hide from swagger but still work when call.
[image]